# Different types in case expression result in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, case

I'm trying to implement some kind of message parser in Haskell, so I decided to use types for message types, not constructors:

```haskell
data DebugMsg  = DebugMsg String
data UpdateMsg = UpdateMsg [String]
```

.. and so on. I belive it is more useful to me, because I can define typeclass, say, `Msg` for message with all information/parsers/actions related to this message. 
But I have problem here. When I try to write parsing function using `case`:

```haskell
parseMsg :: (Msg a) => Int -> Get a
parseMsg code = 
    case code of
        1 -> (parse :: Get DebugMsg)
        2 -> (parse :: Get UpdateMsg)
```

..type of case result should be *same* in *all* branches. Is there any solution? And does it even possible specifiy only typeclass for function result and expect it to be fully polymorphic?

Comment: It's up for the calling context to determine the exact type, not your function's implementation. Stick to ADTs and don't try clever solutions involving typeclasses until you actually need them.

Comment: Yeah, a simple sum type would be fine here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, all the right hand sides of all your subcases must have the exact same type; and this type must be the same as the type of the whole `case` expression.  This is a *feature*; it's required for the language to be able to guarantee at compilation time that there cannot be any type errors at runtime.

Some of the comments on your question mention that the simplest solution is to use a sum (a.k.a. variant) type:

```
data ParserMsg = DebugMsg String | UpdateMsg [String]
```

A consequence of this is that the set of alternative results is defined ahead of time.  This is sometimes an upside (your code can be certain that there are no unhandled subcases), sometimes a downside (there is a finite number of subcases and they are determined at compilation time).

A more advanced solution in some cases—which you might not need, but I'll just throw it in—is to refactor the code to *use functions as data*.  The idea is that you create a datatype that has functions (or monadic actions) as its fields, and then different behaviors = different functions as record fields.

Compare these two styles with this example.  First, specifying different cases as a sum (this uses GADTs, but should be simple enough to understand):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Data.Vector (Vector, (!))
import qualified Data.Vector as V

type Size = Int    
type Index = Int

-- | A 'Frame' translates between a set of values and consecutive array 
-- indexes.  (Note: this simplified implementation doesn't handle duplicate
-- values.)
data Frame p where 
    -- | A 'SimpleFrame' is backed by just a 'Vector'
    SimpleFrame  :: Vector p -> Frame p
    -- | A 'ProductFrame' is a pair of 'Frame's.
    ProductFrame :: Frame p -> Frame q -> Frame (p, q)

getSize :: Frame p -> Size
getSize (SimpleFrame v) = V.length v
getSize (ProductFrame f g) = getSize f * getSize g

getIndex :: Frame p -> Index -> p
getIndex (SimpleFrame v) i = v!i
getIndex (ProductFrame f g) ij = 
    let (i, j) = splitIndex (getSize f, getSize g) ij
    in (getIndex f i, getIndex g j)

pointIndex :: Eq p => Frame p -> p -> Maybe Index
pointIndex (SimpleFrame v) p = V.elemIndex v p
pointIndex (ProductFrame f g) (p, q) = 
    joinIndexes (getSize f, getSize g) (pointIndex f p) (pointIndex g q)

joinIndexes :: (Size, Size) -> Index -> Index -> Index
joinIndexes (_, rsize) i j = i * rsize + j

splitIndex :: (Size, Size) -> Index -> (Index, Index)
splitIndex (_, rsize) ij = (ij `div` rsize, ij `mod` rsize)
```

In this first example, a `Frame` can only ever be either a `SimpleFrame` or a `ProductFrame`, and every `Frame` function must be defined to handle both cases.

Second, datatype with function members (I elide code common to both examples):

```
data Frame p = Frame { getSize    :: Size
                     , getIndex   :: Index -> p
                     , pointIndex :: p -> Maybe Index }

simpleFrame :: Eq p => Vector p -> Frame p
simpleFrame v = Frame (V.length v) (v!) (V.elemIndex v)

productFrame :: Frame p -> Frame q -> Frame (p, q)
productFrame f g = Frame newSize getI pointI
    where newSize = getSize f * getSize g
          getI ij = let (i, j) = splitIndex (getSize f, getSize g) ij 
                    in (getIndex f i, getIndex g j)
          pointI (p, q) = joinIndexes (getSize f, getSize g) 
                                      (pointIndex f p) 
                                      (pointIndex g q)
```

Here the `Frame` type takes the `getIndex` and `pointIndex` operations as data members of the `Frame` itself.  There isn't a fixed compile-time set of subcases, because the behavior of a `Frame` is determined by its element functions, which are supplied at runtime.  So without having to touch those definitions, we could add:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))

concatFrame :: Frame p -> Frame p -> Frame p
concatFrame f g = Frame newSize getI pointI
    where newSize = getSize f + getSize g
          getI ij | ij < getSize f = ij
                  | otherwise      = ij - getSize f
          pointI p = getPoint f p <|> fmap (+(getSize f)) (getPoint g p)
```

I call this second style "behavioral types," but that really is just me.

Note that type classes in GHC are implemented similarly to this—there is a hidden "dictionary" argument passed around, and this dictionary is a record whose members are implementations for the class methods:

```
data ShowDictionary a { primitiveShow :: a -> String }

stringShowDictionary :: ShowDictionary String
stringShowDictionary = ShowDictionary { primitiveShow = ... }

-- show "whatever"
-- ---> primitiveShow stringShowDictionary "whatever"
```

Comment: The moral of this story is that you can replace a class and its instances with a record type of functions and some data, and that can make your solution _much_ cleaner.

Comment: Good answer, although the first sentence "all the right hand sides of all your subcases must have the exact same type" isn't strictly true. The right hand sides all must have a type at least as general as the specified return type (e.g. the alternatives could return `undefined :: a`, `Nothing :: Maybe b` and `Just True`), resp., if the return type is inferred and not specified, they must all unify.

Comment: @Daniel There's nothing wrong with saying that `undefined :: Int`, it's just that `Int` isn't the most general type it has.  So I think saying that all right hand sides of a case must have the exact same type is an accurate statement.

Comment: @augustss Taking all right hand sides together, they all get the exact same type. But regarded in isolation, the types of some may be more general than that of others. Shall we (awkwardly) say "They all must be able to have the exact same type"? Probably better to say they must have a _common_ type.

Comment: I would indeed say that `undefined :: Int` as augustss says, because, well, `undefined` is in fact a proof of `Int` (though of course only in an unsound language). Even without that, well, my point put more precisely is that in a `case` expression, the type of the whole expression and the types of the subcases' RHS will unify.

Comment: "the type of the whole expression and the types of the subcases' RHS will unify" Precisely. And my point was that "the exact same type" is - in my reading - not quite the way to put it.

Answer (score 9):

You *could* accomplish something like this with existential types, however it wouldn't work how you want it to, so you really shouldn't.

Doing it with normal polymorphism, as you have in your example, won't work at all. What your type says is that the function is valid for *all* `a`--that is, the caller gets to choose what kind of message to receive. However, you have to choose the message based on the numeric code, so this clearly won't do.

To clarify: all standard Haskell type variables are universally quantified by default. You can read your type signature as `∀a. Msg a => Int -> Get a`. What this says is that the function is define for *every* value of `a`, regardless of what the argument may be. This means that it has to be able to return whatever particular `a` the caller wants, regardless of what argument it gets.

What you really want is something like `∃a. Msg a => Int -> Get a`. This is why I said you could do it with existential types. However, this is relatively complicated in Haskell (you can't quite write a type signature like that) and will not actually solve your problem correctly; it's just something to keep in mind for the future.

Fundamentally, using classes and types like this is not very idiomatic in Haskell, because that's not what classes are meant to do. You would be much better off sticking to a normal algebraic data type for your messages.

I would have a single type like this:

```
data Message = DebugMsg String
             | UpdateMsg [String]
```

So instead of having a `parse` function per type, just do the parsing in the `parseMsg` function as appropriate:

```
parseMsg :: Int -> String -> Message
parseMsg n msg = case n of
  1 -> DebugMsg msg
  2 -> UpdateMsg [msg]
```

(Obviously fill in whatever logic you actually have there.)

Essentially, this is the classical use for normal algebraic data types. There is no reason to have different types for the different kinds of messages, and life is much easier if they have the same type.

It looks like you're trying to emulate sub-typing from other languages. As a rule of thumb, you use algebraic data types in place of most of the uses of sub-types in other languages. This is certainly one of those cases.

Comment: Thanks for great answer! Now things getting clear to me. I wanted to parse body of message, not body with code, and suggested that selecting instance by return type here is fine. My first code snippet used constructors with pattern matching, as you proposed, but I wanted to organize code more... clean, so each message has everything related to it in one place (it is about hundread of message types, by the way). My suggestion was "if function can take any argument that has instance of specified typeclass, there must be a way for any type that has specified instances to be result of function".